# Command line dig tool doesn't get answer for SOA query, while https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/dig/#SOA/ DOES

Tags: domain-name-system, dig

While running in my windows 10 64bits machine this command: `dig gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com ANY`

I get this response

```
; <<>> DiG 9.16.2 <<>> gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com ANY
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: FORMERR, id: 31969
;; flags: qr rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
; COOKIE: 54719e117b6518e0 (echoed)
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.    IN      ANY

;; Query time: 163 msec
;; SERVER: 10.8.1.10#53(10.8.1.10)
;; WHEN: Thu May 14 11:10:17 Argentina Standard Time 2020
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 67
```

But if I use google dig toolbox at https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/dig/#SOA/ I actually get this:

```
id 8747
opcode QUERY
rcode NOERROR
flags QR RD RA
;QUESTION
gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com. IN SOA
;ANSWER
;AUTHORITY
l.google.com. 59 IN SOA ns1.google.com. dns-admin.google.com. 311303408 900 900 1800 60
;ADDITIONAL
```

Why the different behavior?

Comment: What is `10.8.1.10` and why is it responding with an error?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to know exactly why your resolver `10.8.1.10` responds with the error code `FORMERR` (although I can speculate somewhat, at the end of the answer).

The query itself is a bit odd as well, there is no expectation that there should be a `SOA` record at `gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com` and the successful response you get via the G Suite Toolbox as well as my example below confirm that there is indeed no such record (as you see, in both cases there is a `NODATA` response).
That said, if you want to run a more directly equivalent `dig` command that does not rely so much on your local environment being in working order, this would be an example of that (and I expect it will work for you too):

```
$ dig @8.8.8.8 gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com SOA

; <<>> DiG 9.11.18-RedHat-9.11.18-1.fc32 <<>> @8.8.8.8 gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com SOA
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 38855
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.    IN      SOA

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
l.google.com.           59      IN      SOA     ns1.google.com. dns-admin.google.com. 311303408 900 900 1800 60

;; Query time: 21 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
;; WHEN: Thu May 14 16:55:22 UTC 2020
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 105

$
```

As for how to troubleshoot the problem with `10.8.1.10`, I would suggest trying these in order to see if it's related to mishandling of edns cookies, mishandling of edns in general or some problem I did not guess.

- `dig gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com SOA +nocookie`
- `dig gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com SOA +noedns`

If you are the operator of `10.8.1.10` you then have some input on what problem is, where the solution likely involves upgrading the resolver server software to a fixed version. 
If you are not the operator, I suppose you can pass on the information about the problem to the operator.

Comment: Many thanks for your response Hakan, I finally understand that there's no SOA record for that MX host, and that plus we're having a bug now with our java based dns resolver which is returning authoritative servers as they were SOA records. Thanks again!

Comment: Actually our java based tool was returning smth like this: "there are SOA records for this domain l.google.com but not for this gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com"

Comment: @FernandoRomero I think you may be misinterpreting the responses that you describe the these latest comments.  What a `NODATA` response looks like is: status `NOERROR` + the `SOA` for the matching *zone* in the `AUTHORITY` section (not to be confused with whether a response is authoritative). And what `NODATA` means is that the requested record type does not exist at the requested name.

Comment: @FernandoRomero For reference, compare the output of `dig @8.8.8.8 gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com SOA` to the output of `dig @8.8.8.8 l.google.com SOA`

Comment: So, the AUTHORITY section is pointing me to the host which can provide me with the AUTHORITATIVE response?